# Printing to PDF from Excel w/bookmarks

Tags: .net, excel

I'm programmatically creating many sheets in an Excel workbook. When I'm done I need to print the workbook to a pdf. That is working using this code

```
oBook.PrintOut(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, "Adobe PDF", true, Type.Missing, filename)
Process.Start(filename)
```

So, I print to postscript using the Adobe PDF printer instance and then open the .ps file to distill it. Everything works fine. What I need to do, however, is add bookmarks to the PDF file. All I need is the name of each sheet as a bookmark. Can I do that using the above method?

I know it can be done using the "Create PDF" option from Excel, which appears to use PDFMaker. Is there a way to call that from .NET?

Thanks for any help, I really appreciate it.

Thanks,
Nick